# Print array from PHP in the jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can print date and age (in following array) separate by `$.ajax()`?

php:

```
$array = array(
                'date' => 2011/9/14,
                'age' => 48,
            );
return $array // this send for ajax call in the jQuery
```

I want this output by jquery:`2011/9/14` & `48`

Comment: I think you should get your understanding of client-server, jQuery, AJAX, POST, PHP etc. straight.

Comment: +1 @Baszz. @Selena `json_encode` and `echo` are your friends in this situation, `return` isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $.ajax Methods and setting parameter dataType to JSON for receive data type JSON from PHP file.

Jquery Code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getdata.php",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    alert("Date:" + data.date + "\n" + "Age:" + data.age);
  }
});
```

if your array data contains string make sure it's closured with quote then make data type JSON with json_encode() function.

PHP Code (getdata.php):

```
$array= array('date'=>'2011/9/14','age'=>48);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the array as a valid JSON string using the PHP function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). You can then use the jQuery function [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert it into a JavaScript object. From there you'll be able to do whatever you want with it.

If you do this, you'll end up with an object like:

```
ajaxDataObj = {
    date: '2011/9/14',
    age: 48
}
```

****Edit****
Please see stratton's comment below about using $.getJSON for a more compact solution.
Also, Ben Everard's comment on your original post about using echo rather than return is critical.

Comment: if you use $.getJSON instead it can all be incorporated in a single ajax function

Answer (score 1):

Echo the encoded array in php page say mypage.php
using

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

And use jQuery.getJson in the client side

```
$.getJSON('mypage.php', function(data) {
  alert(data['date']);
  alert(data['age']);
});
```

Comment: Excellent one! this code is very useful especially when you are using $.post instead of $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can't just return `$array` to the browser, the result will be "Array" as string.
YOu have to use `return json_encode($array);` which returns a string that could be parsed by browser.

Comment: i not use of json, did there is other way?

Answer (score 0):

If the server-client communication is working alright, then you should do something like this on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    //configuration...
    'success':function(response){
        var dateAge = response.date+' & '+response.age;
        //put or append the string somewhere. 
    }
});
```